# Is it possible to install gstreamer GStreamer Core and Plugins 1.6.3 stable release on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, gstreamer

For my recording project I need to use a tool which needs a new version of gstreamer. I've seen that 1.6.3 is the last stable version of it but don't know if it's possible to install it on my system (ubuntu 14.04 / 4.1.6-040106-generic) if yes, what's the easiest way to install?

What about kernel 3.16.0-57-generic? which stable version of gstreamer do you suggest to install on this kernel?

p.s: I've tried the main repos but it seems they install an older version which is not good for my purpose.

Any help is appreciate it.

Comment: you could build it from source

Comment: how new do you need? ubuntu 15.10 has version 1.6.0

Comment: I'm on 14.04 therefor I need to install the newest stable version on it (at least 1.5) on both of the kernel versions mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to compile it from source you can run the following commands.

First, install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool build-essential ubuntu-restricted-extras autopoint flex bison gtk-doc-tools
```

Then, download the sourcecode:

```
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.6.3.tar.xz
```

Extract the file and change to the directory of the extracted file:

```
tar xvf gstreamer-1.6.3.tar.xz
cd gstreamer-1.6.3
```

Now, run the following command:

```
./autogen.sh
```

You should see no errors here and it should return the line "`Now type 'make' to compile gstreamer.`"

Compile the code:

```
make
```

At the end of the output, you should see no errors in the lines beginning with `make[4]`, `make[1]`, `make[2]`, or `make[3]`.

Run the following command to test:

```
./tools/gst-launch-1.0 -v fakesrc num_buffers=5 ! fakesink
```

If you see no errors, proceed.

Finally, install gstreamer 1.6.3:

```
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

[Click here to see more plugins (ugly, bad, good, base)](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/?C=M;O=D).

---

You have two options,the easy way and the hard way. First:

**THE HARD WAY**

Here is how to compile the plugins. First install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep orc gst-plugins-base1.0 gst-plugins-good1.0 gst-plugins-bad1.0 gst-plugins-ugly1.0 gst-libav1.0
```

Next, make a directory to work in and download the source packages:

```
mkdir PLUGINS
cd PLUGINS
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/orc/orc-0.4.24.tar.xz 
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-libav/gst-libav-1.6.3.tar.xz 
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-base/gst-plugins-base-1.6.3.tar.xz 
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-good/gst-plugins-good-1.6.3.tar.xz 
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-bad/gst-plugins-bad-1.6.3.tar.xz 
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-ugly/gst-plugins-ugly-1.6.3.tar.xz
```

Extract the archives:

```
tar xvf gst*lib*xz
tar xvf g*p*b*e*z
tar xvf g*p*g*g*d*z
tar xvf g*p*b*d*z
tar xvf g*p*y*z
tar xvf orc* 

cd orc
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

Ignore any warnings; there should be no errors.

---

**base plugins**

```
cd g*base*
./configure
```

If there are plugins listed under `configure: *** Plug-ins with dependencies that will NOT be built:` you may need to install dependencies for them.

For example, if `ogg` is listed, run the following command to search for available packages:

```
apt-cache search libogg | grep dev
```

Among the listed packages should be `libogg-dev`. To install it, just use apt-get like so:

```
sudo apt-get install libogg-dev
```

I could not find dependencies that satisfy `ivorbisdec` so don't worry about that one unless you really need it. Run ./configure again after installing dependencies and then proceed if you are satisfied.

```
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

Again, there should be no errors on the lines near the end of the output: `make[4]`, `make[3]`, `make[2]`, and `make[1]`.

---

**good plugins**

```
cd g*good*
./configure
```

Do the same here with the dependencies. I was not able to find the dependencies for the following plugins:

directsoundsink

osxaudio

osxvideosink

sunaudio

waveformsink

Again, run `./configure` after adding dependencies and proceed when you are satisfied:

```
make 
sudo make install
```

---

**bad plugins**

```
cd g*bad*
./configure
```

There was a whole list of plugins not built here, I didn't even try to track down. If you have problems with GStreamer later on like if something doesn't work, you can check but I wouldn't bother here unless there are issues.

```
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

---

Do the same for the remaining plugins.

---

**THE EASY WAY**

To install ppa versions through apt-get, run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dan-witt/gstreamer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0
```

This will install gstreamer and all the plugins version 1.6.

[Click here for more info about the ppa.](https://launchpad.net/~dan-witt/+archive/ubuntu/gstreamer)

Comment: First of all thank you! Shall I remove the prev. version first? and one more thing, I couldn't understand how to install (clone) the good plugins first, don't they get installed when I install the gstreamer itself automatically?

Comment: @SinaSh You shouldn't need to remove it because it installs under /usr/local/bin. /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin on your $PATH so the system should use whatever is in /usr/local/bin first. I will post more instructions for the plugins.

Comment: @SinaSh If you haven't already built the plugins, I found a ppa that will install the version 1.6 plugins through apt-get **THE EASY WAY** Instructions are at the end of my post.

Comment: The steps are old. You're better off reading the README in gstreamer-1.19.1.tar.xz to install latest gstreamer. It uses meson and ninja.